# Can't update index dynamically with dexie sample code

Tags: dexie

I have been trying updating the db index dynamically and keeps failed, stuck for a few days. 
I'm using angular7 & type script and latest dexie version. When I try to use the same code, it give me error:

Is there anything I should do to get it working? Thx!

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): UpgradeError: Dexie specification of currently installed DB version is missing
UpgradeError: Dexie specification of currently installed DB version is missing
```

I literally just copy pasted the sample code here:

```
 changeSchema(db, schemaChanges) {
    db.close();
    const newDb = new Dexie(db.name);
    newDb.version(db.verno + 1).stores(schemaChanges);
    return newDb.open();
  }

  // Open database dynamically:
  async playAround() {
    let db = new Dexie('FriendsDatabase');
    if (!(await Dexie.exists(db.name))) {
      db.version(1).stores({});
    }
    await db.open();

    // Add a table with some indexes:
    db = await this.changeSchema(db, { friends: 'id, name' });

    // Add another index in the friends table
    db = await this.changeSchema(db, { friends: 'id, name, age' });

    // Remove the age index again:
    db = await this.changeSchema(db, { friends: 'id, name' });

    // Remove the friends table
    db = await this.changeSchema(db, { friends: null });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sample was faulty. I've updated the docs with a working sample:

```js
async function changeSchema(db, schemaChanges) {
  db.close();
  const newDb = new Dexie(db.name);

  newDb.on('blocked', ()=>false); // Silence console warning of blocked event.

  // Workaround: If DB is empty from tables, it needs to be recreated
  if (db.tables.length === 0) {
    await db.delete();
    newDb.version(1).stores(schemaChanges);
    return await newDb.open();
  }

  // Extract current schema in dexie format:
  const currentSchema = db.tables.reduce((result,{name, schema}) => {
    result[name] = [
      schema.primKey.src,
      ...schema.indexes.map(idx => idx.src)
    ].join(',');
    return result;
  }, {});

  console.log("Version: " + db.verno);
  console.log("Current Schema: ", currentSchema);

  // Tell Dexie about current schema:
  newDb.version(db.verno).stores(currentSchema);
  // Tell Dexie about next schema:
  newDb.version(db.verno + 1).stores(schemaChanges);
  // Upgrade it:
  return await newDb.open();    
}

// Open database dynamically:
async function playAround() {
  let db = new Dexie ('FriendsDatabase2');
  if (!(await Dexie.exists(db.name))) {
      console.log("Db does not exist");
      db.version(1).stores({});
  }
  await db.open();
  console.log("Could open DB")

  // Add a table with some indexes:
  db = await changeSchema(db, {friends: 'id, name'});
  console.log("Could enforce friends table with id and name")

  // Add another index in the friends table
  db = await changeSchema(db, {friends: 'id, name, age'});
  console.log("Could add the age index")

  // Remove the age index again:
  db = await changeSchema(db, {friends: 'id, name'})
  console.log("Could remove age index")

  // Remove the friends table
  db = await changeSchema(db, {friends: null});
  console.log("Could delete friends table")
}

playAround().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dfahlander/jzf2mc7n/